# Complete .NET solution for asset minification and bundling?

Tags: .net, css, performance, less, bundling-and-minification

We are just about to start up a new quite big .NET 4.5 project and we are looking for a solution to handle our static assets such as Javascript and CSS-files. In short we want it to be a solution where it's easy to develop and debug in development environment, and maximum performance and cache control in production.

## Requirements

- Must support LESS.
- Must be able to control the order of bundled JS/CSS-files.
- Must be able to bundle a subset of files in a directory, not every file.
- File hash or last modified timestamp must be appended to CSS/JS-file names as querystring (eg main.js?3B1F88A7) to break client cache on file update.
- If web.config compilation debug is set to "on" I want to include the files as separate script/link-tags to simplify development and debugging (development mode).
- If web.config compilation debug is set to "off" I want to minify and bundle the files to a single CSS/JS-file and set aggressive cache headers (production mode).
- Bundling and minification is done when the user requests the page, not a post-build script.
- Must be able to have multiple JS/CSS bundles in same website to support more than one website/different bundles on certain sub pages.
- Must support a production environment with multiple servers.

## Nice to have

- It would be nice if it does not break the intellisense (CSS class names etc).

I did check out the new minification and bundling tools in .NET 4.5 (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx) and I also checked out Cassette (http://getcassette.net/) but AFAIK none of them meets all our requirements "out of the box".

So, what do you consider as best practise? Should we go with a a third party solution like Cassette, a custom built solution on the .NET 4.5 features (I like this one because it's "standard .NET", but does not support .LESS) or something completely different?

Any ideas or thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Can you please explain specifically how the built-in bundling and minification features don't meet your needs?

Comment: I'm sure everything CAN be done with the new stuff in .NET 4.5, but from what I understand it has no out-of-the-box LESS support, cache busting features, custom order of bundled files etc.

SquishIt has it all in simple NuGet packages, ready to go and lots of other sites running the exact same code as I am.

Comment: Cache busting, custom order of bundled files is exactly what the built-in stuff does (i.e. it does pretty much everything in your requirements). LESS support takes about 3 lines of code to make happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt) is the solution you looking for

Comment: Agreed. SquishIt meets all of these requirements out of the box.

Comment: SquishIt looks like a perfect match but where can i find the documentation? I only found a quick "get started" guide at http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher

Comment: You can use project [wiki](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/wiki) on github, stackoverflow questions and [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/squishit)

Comment: That's not what I call a proper documentation :)